# Jump to the last xml element in php

Tags: php, xml

```
<Basketball>
    <Game>
        <Host>
            <Host_name>LA Lakers</Host_name>
            <Result>108</Result>
        </Host>
        <Guest>
            <Guest_name>Miami Heat</Guest_name>
            <Result>95</Result>
        </Guest>
    </Game>
    <Game>
        <Host>
            <Host_name>Boston Celtics</Host_name>
            <Result>88</Result>
        </Host>
        <Guest>
            <Guest_name>Sand Antonio Spurs</Guest_name>
            <Result>94</Result>
        </Guest>
    </Game>
</Basketball>
```

I'm trying to reach the end of the last `<Game>` and continue writing from that point/line. Is that possible? I didn't write any php for that so far. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php

Comment: I don't want to sound harsh, but most likely the problem is that you didn't wrote any line of PHP so far. If you want to learn how it can be done, the PHP Manual guides you already: http://php.net/domnode.appendchild http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic - And there is no *jump* in XML because there is no pointer or cursor. There are only *Nodes*.